# Getting Mail List from iphone Mail app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can we access Mails List from iphone Mail app. I need to get a list of mail in my native app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available in the SDK and there is no way to do it without a jailbreak.

Comment: thanks, one more can we access events form iphone Calendar app.

Comment: hey buddy, there is EventKit which you can use for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765

Answer (score -1):

No, Apple doesn't allow a such thing. (and you can't access to message either)
but you can use EventKit for Reminders and Calendars